# VB won't show PDF Reader

Tags: vb.net, pdf, process

I use the following Code to Open a PDF File:

```
Public Sub Execute_Doc(afilename As String, Optional style As ProcessWindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized)
        Dim myProcess As New Process

        Const ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND As Integer = 2
        Const ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED As Integer = 5


        Try
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = afilename
            myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = style
            myProcess.Start()
        Catch e As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
            If e.NativeErrorCode = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Then
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". Check the path.")
                MsgBox("File<" + afilename + "> not found!")
            Else
                If e.NativeErrorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED Then
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". You do not have permission to print this file.")
                    MsgBox("File <" + afilename + "> couldn't be opened!")
                End If
            End If
            MsgBox(e.ToString())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(e.ToString())
        Finally
            myProcess.Kill()
            myProcess.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I call Execute_Doc("C:\ProgrammName\Test.pdf", ProcessWindowStyle.Normal) but the Adobe Reader won't show up. I can see it in the Task Manager.

Well it works if I start Adobe Reader first without any files by clicking the default Icon on my Desktop. It also works with the integrated PDF Reader from Windows 8.1. I can't debug this isse on my Windows 7 / VS 2013 Computer. The problem only exists on ONE! client computer.

Any tipps how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Execute_Doc(afilename As String, Optional style As ProcessWindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized)
    Dim myProcess As New Process

    Const ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND As Integer = 2
    Const ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED As Integer = 5


    Try
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe " & afilename
        myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = style
        myProcess.Start()
    Catch e As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        If e.NativeErrorCode = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Then
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". Check the path.")
            MsgBox("File<" + afilename + "> not found!")
        Else
            If e.NativeErrorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED Then
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". You do not have permission to print this file.")
                MsgBox("File <" + afilename + "> couldn't be opened!")
            End If
        End If
        MsgBox(e.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(e.ToString())
    Finally
        myProcess.Kill()
        myProcess.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is thery any way without AcroRd32.exe? I want to use the default PDF Viewer (Adobe Reader, Build-in Microsoft, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Shell Execute it is provided by the Win API so you do not have to worry about what program is installed to handle the extension. Windows does the work for you.

```
Private Function ShellExecute(ByVal File As String) As Boolean
   Dim myProcess As New Process
   myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = File
   myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
   myProcess.Start()
   myProcess.Dispose()
End Function
```